# Cannot deploy contracts on local ganache instance

Tags: blockchain, truffle, ganache

[image]

Don't know why, but getting this error. I tried account from ganache that has 100 ETHs. The compilation was successfully done but when I try to deploy the error arises. Pls help...!

Comment: Your balance is 0 wei; make sure that you're connecting to the right blockchain

Comment: Can you share the truffle configuration? What command are your executing? Any detail to reproduce the error will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, here are the changes which i did to make my code work:

1. If you are using ethers.js ,downgrade it to version 5.6.2.
2. Now add some manual gas amount to deploy the code such as:

```
    const overrides = { gasLimit: 6000000 }; 
    console.log("Deploying Please Wait...");
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(overrides);
```

3. use fs-extra rather than fs.

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
```

Here is a sample code which you can refer to fix your code:

```
// Ganache is a fake blockchain (machine), which we can run locally to test, deploy, run contracts.
//http://127.0.0.1:7545

// ether.js is a package which allows us to interact with different blockchains, make all API calls with
// EVM compatible chains.

// except ether there is also a package web3.js

const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
    // below written both lines give us all to interact with smart contracts,
    // the first line connects us to the blockchain,
    // the second line gives us a wallet with private key to sign the tranx.

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"); // saying hey we want to connect to this url.

    // now lets get the private keys and address,
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
        YOUR_PRIVATE KEY,
        provider
    );

    // now to interact with any contract we need 2 things as we know: Address and ABI
    const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
    const binary = fs.readFileSync(
        "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
        "utf8"
    );
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
    const overrides = { gasLimit: 6000000 }; 
    console.log("Deploying Please Wait...");
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(overrides);
    console.log(contract);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, like the error said *you have insufficient funds*.
This probably means the address you try to deploy the contracts with (in your case `0x49Bf...398b5`) has never been used before on the network.

You should be able to fix this problem easily by:

1. transferring some ETH to the deploying wallet or
2. getting some ETH from a faucet

and then executing `2_deploy_contracts.js` again.